# Philips Hue API: Remove application/username from bridge in order to start over

Tags: api, philips-hue

I'm using the HueSDK_iOS and everything seems to work fine.

I have one simple question for which I cannot seem to find a simple answer.
I want to test my app's functionality whenever a new user installs it.

I cannot find a proper way to de-authenticate my app from the bridge, so it will ask again to search for bridges etc and I can start over, to test everything.

I /did/ use :

```
cache = [PHBridgeResourcesReader readBridgeResourcesCache];
PHBridgeConfiguration *config = [cache bridgeConfiguration];
PHBridgeSendAPI *sendAPI = [[PHBridgeSendAPI alloc] init];  
[sendAPI removeWhitelistEntryWithUsername:[config username] completionHandler:^(NSArray *errors) {
     ...
}];
```

and in the first time, it returns no errors, but I still am authenticated and can use the API , control lights etc, no notification arrives for disconnection or noLocalConnection.

If I run it again, I get an error:  error =     {\n        address = \"/config/whitelist/_a_user_name\";\n        description = \"resource, /config/whitelist/_a_user_name, not available\";\n        type = 3;\n

(where a "_a_user_name" is the automatically generated username)

but I still keep being authenticated to the bridge.
So it seems it does delete the username from the whitelist, but still everything works as if I was authenticated.

So the question is simple: How do I remove my app from the bridge so I can start over and test all the steps? (Pushlinking etc)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears it is a bug in the bridge software as I was informed by Philips API support. They asked me to wait for an update.

Answer (score 0):

According to [this](https://developers.meethue.com/develop/hue-api/7-configuration-api/#del-user-from-whitelist) it can only be done through https://account.meethue.com/apps starting with API version `1.31.0`.